# uimaFIT creating type system

Tags: uima, uimafit

When creating types, what are the benefit of having different type descriptors for each type rather than use a one type descriptor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reason might be purely cosmetic. For example, you could want to group types into different files depending on their use. E.g. you might want to keep type related to document structure in one file while you put put types related to semantic relations into another file. When you write a program, you also usually don't put all code into one file.

There could also be a technical reason. E.g in DKPro Core, the jcasgen-maven-plugin is used to automatically generate JCas classes for some type system files. These JCas classes are not checked in to the version control system. However, specific type system files are excluded from this automatic generation and the respective JCas classes are actually checked in to the version control system because they contain custom modifications - i.e. extra manually implemented methods.

*Disclosure: I am a working on both, uimaFIT and DKPro Core.*

Comment: Thank you @Rec :)

Comment: I have many troubles to create the Type System with uima-fit. I've already created the types with JCasGen as I did with uima, but the type system can't be found even if I created the file types.txt in META-INF/ org.apache.uima.fit/ folder. Can you suggest me how to solve the binding of the type system that I've defined in the xml file with the analysis engine? Thank you!

Comment: You can set up a logging configuration file and set the log level for the class `org.apache.uima.fit.factory.TypeSystemDescriptionFactory` to `DEBUG` - that generate log messages telling you type systems could be located by uimaFIT. Maybe that gives you a hint why your own descriptors are not found. You can also manually load your descriptors and pass them as arguments to uimaFIT methods such as `createEngine(...)`.